# Global keyboard states

Tags: xna, architecture

I have following idea about processing keyboard input. We capture input in "main" Game class like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    this.CurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    // main :Game class logic here

    base.Update(gameTime);

    this.PreviousKeyboardState = this.CurrentKeyboardState;
}
```

then, reuse keyboard states (which have `internal` scope) in all other game components. The reasons behind this are 1) minimize keyboard processing load, and 2) reduce "pollution" of all other classes with similar keyboard state variables.

Since I'm quite a noob in both game and XNA development, I would like to know if all of this sounds reasonable.

**UPDATE:** If someone is interested, actual utility class, as suggested by *David Gouveia*, I've created [can be found here](https://bitbucket.org/pabdulin/conjurer/src/1d81f5e8028b/Conjurer/Input/KeyboardManager.cs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly reasonable, and I could leave it at that!

... but personally I prefer having a bit more encapsulation. So instead of managing the state inside the `Game` class and providing global access to it, I prefer wrapping it in its own class instead.

Here's an example from memory. Not sure if I missed some detail but what's important is the general idea:

```
public static class InputManager
{
    public static void Update()
    {
        _previousKeyboardState = _currentKeyboardState;
        _currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
    }

    public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key) 
    {
        return _currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key);
    }

    public static bool IsKeyUp(Keys key)
    {
        return _currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(key);
    }

    public static bool OnKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        return _currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key) && _previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(key);
    }

    public static bool OnKeyUp(Keys key)
    {
        return _currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(key) && _previousKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key);
    }

    private static KeyboardState _currentKeyboardState;
    private static KeyboardState _previousKeyboardState;
}
```

Then at the top of `Game.Update` I simply call Update on the manager:

```
InputManager.Update();
```

And finally everywhere else on the game I can use the wrapper directly:

```
if(InputManager.OnKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
    // Shoot once
}
```

Some advantages:

- Like in your solution, there's only one place in the application that needs to manage the current and previous keyboard states.
- But instead of polluting the game class with keyboard processing, it's encapsulated in its own class just for that.
- The class is static making it globally accessible, so that if you don't want you don't need to provide global access to your game class.
- It's also easily reusable - if you start a new project, you can just drop that class in and you're good to go.

Comment: While you're at it, make the API easy to record and play back.  This way you can use canned inputs for testing purposes later.

Comment: @PatrickHughes could you please elaborate a little on your comment? What kind of approaches can I take for this? Some links could be useful.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin You would want to keep a list of `KeyboardState` objects associated with timestamps in a struct. As you play your game for testing, grab the `gameTime.TotalGameTime` each frame and put it in a struct with the `_currentKeyboardState` and on game quit write that list of `KeyboardState`s and `TimeSpan.Milliseconds` `int`s to disk. Then when you run the game in test-input mode, read the `KeyboardState`s and `int`s from this file and read them from the list checking that the next `KeyboardState`'s associated timestamp matches the current `gameTime.TotalGameTime.Milliseconds` property.

Comment: @michael.bartnett thank you very much for detailed explanation. This all makes sense.